# TypeScript type in a for... in loop on an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am using for... in loop to iterate over an object using square brackets notation, TypeScript complains saying the following:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'EVENT'.   No index signature
> with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'EVENT'.ts(7053)

I Know if this wasn't a loop I could tell TypeScript that "a" can be only certain values, but by using a loop I can't give types so I don't know what to do
The problem is I think I can't tell Typescript that in event[a] "a" can take a few values only

```
interface EVENT {
    imageURL: string;
    artist: string;
    location: string;
    city: string;
    seat: number;
    direction: string;
    country: string;
    type: string;
    date: string;
    tickets_available: number;
    tickets_left: number;
    id: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
  }
data.filter((event: EVENT) => {
        // a = key of the object data
        for (let a in event) {
          let aSplit =
            typeof event[a] === "string"
              ? event[a].split(" ").map((element: string) => element.toLowerCase())
              : event[a];
          // b = word of searchTerm string
          for (let b of querySplit) {
            if (
              a === "artist" ||
              a === "location" ||
              a === "city" ||
              a === "country" ||
              a === "type"
            ) {
              if (aSplit.includes(b.toLowerCase())) matches.push(event);
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

I am using the latest typescript with the latest nextJS framework, tsconfig set to aim for ES2015
[ScreenShot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrlP.png)

Comment: You can use Object.keys with an assertion `as (keyof EVENT)[]` as an alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the TypeScript error says, "The left-hand side of a 'for...in' statement cannot use a type annotation."

However, you can create a typed variable within the `for...in` loop that does have a type, and use that to index your object.

Here's a modified version of the snippet in your question. I've added an empty `data` variable and removed the `querySplit` code because those parts don't have the necessary context in your snippet to resolve TypeScript errors.

You'll also note I had to replace your `event[a]` code with a variable, because accessing the value using square bracket notation repeatedly doesn't work properly with TypeScript's type narrowing.

```
interface EVENT {
    imageURL: string;
    artist: string;
    location: string;
    city: string;
    seat: number;
    direction: string;
    country: string;
    type: string;
    date: string;
    tickets_available: number;
    tickets_left: number;
    id: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
}

// Just creating an empty array so TypeScript doesn't complain about `data`
let data: EVENT[] = [];

data.filter((event: EVENT) => {
    // a = key of the object data
    for (let a in event) {
        // Create new typed variable for this iterations' value of `a`
        const key = a as keyof EVENT;
        // Look up `event[key]` once so TypeScript can narrow its type
        const value = event[key];

        let aSplit = typeof value === "string"
        ? value.split(" ").map((element: string) => element.toLowerCase())
        : value;

        // More stuff here
    }
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-EEkdQut5sllwdasVkQLQctCUnBqNUzBjSaQJZCmILIf4K8BwtkI-7IRRINinc5XG53OSbED8KDSA2acPBCD+zwgRZZT0oVHZsC5yMIjGq2VwS5BSSaFnN6Odr0o5GogBEoi4i-9AH53V2saxx5oCYvkIuqViKEEiRACmRFb0acj6ZftoqsWBpEm9dB1XBDASqVT-Sws4QEOCbIAAspKKDsKYMCcryDgkOMoxUtwQA)

Answer (score 13):

I usually use the following pattern:

```
interface Foo {
    str: string,
    num: number,
}

const foo: Foo = {
    str: "one",
    num: 1,
};

let i: keyof Foo;
for (i in foo) {
    console.log(foo[i]);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIDOYUAXMaaAOYA0+hIArgLYXMsBG09AvrrgToQJZDEwUMWALw4GBEuWQAiYRGX1CyDhQCMfANwCANhDDJgFANYQAnuhhpMR8VGQAKYBZBjMASjktIRF0UwA6Y3Rqd3F0AG1gAF0-I34BIA)

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be forced to use let instead of const, so I did this and it worked, it's a little more verbose, but I'm ok with it:

```
interface Foo {
    str: string,
    num: number,
}

const foo: Foo = {
    str: "one",
    num: 1,
};


for (const i in foo) {
    console.log(foo[i as keyof Foo]);
}
```